# Check if values from two different colums and get value from next column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sequence, vlookup

I think that we can do it with formula, but I cannot get how can skip some cases:

- column A has values different from column C
- column A and Column C have equal number of identical values
- values from column D need to go to column B infront of the corresponding cell
- Column A has repeatable values, also column C has the same repeatable values.[!

[Here is a example of my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpwOW.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Look into VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH

Comment: You cannot do '*impossible things in excel*'. By definition, they are impossible.

Comment: And wrap the formula in an IFERROR() to return `""` when not found.

Comment: @Jeeped - Thank you for the edit and for the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula in B1 and fill down.

```
=IF(LEN(A1), INDEX(D:D, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(D$1:INDEX(D:D, MATCH("zzz", D:D)))/(C$1:INDEX(C:C, MATCH("zzz", D:D))=A1), COUNTIF(A$1:A1, A1))), TEXT(,))
```

[image]

Comment: Is =TEXT(,) equivalent to ="" ?

Comment: Yes and if you get used to using it that way, you can build a formula from a string in  VBA without having to use `""""` everywhere.

Comment: Any reason for this format as opposed to an IFERROR?

Comment: Not really. This may be marginally faster since if the IF fails, no aggregate processing is performed while in a IFERROR the aggregate processing is always performed and the `""` is only supplied on a failure. But I cut the aggregate processing ranges down to the minim um number of cells so the difference is going to be slight.